# How to choose a barcode type

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

I am building a time keeping application for a business.  Their staff will carry a unique barcode (either on a lanyard or as an image on their phone) and will display it to a barcode reader.  The reader will use it to identify the clock-on/clock-off activity of the staff member.

As it currently stands, each staff member already has a unique id.  These are incrementing integers, starting at the digit 1.  At the very most, there may be hundreds or thousands of unique staff members (throughout the duration of the lifetime of my application) but certainly not one million or more.  I am planning to encode this unique ID as the barcode.

Given the above, how should I choose a bar code system?

It seems to me that EAN13 is widely supported by barcode readers, and has ample 'space' for my needs (i.e. less than 1-million unique id's).  This would seem like a good choice.

I see that some other systems include 'error checking', but they include a lot more visual detail.  I presume that these codes would need to be printed carefully (e.g. not on a home printer), and would only useful in well lit environments.

Comment: eeny meeny minie moe

Answer (score 0):

EAN-13 uses "registered" numbers and is primarily for consumer packaging.

If you want a linear barcode, look at code128.  It has a built in check-digit and packs two digits per "character".  You should plan to zero-pad the numbers to 6 or 8 digits so the barcodes are always the same size.  The following shows "000101" in code128:

https://bwipjs-api.metafloor.com/?bcid=code128&text=000101&includetext&backgroundcolor=ffffff

Comment: Ean codes starting with 0 or 2 can be used without registration.

Answer (score 0):

I'd choose QR codes cos they're sick, you can stick a logo in them, and they're just nice in general.